# Need to apply a webkit style in Firefox and vice versa

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I have some text that I need to style but it can run on multiple types of devices.  So with column-count for example, I try to do this:

```
$columnDiv.css({
    '-moz-column-count': value,
    '-webkit-column-count': value,
    'column-count': value,
});
```

but it only will result in the -moz-column-count being applied inline.  Is there anyway to have jquery put in the others regardless of the browser?  In Chrome it would only apply the -webkit-column-count css style.

Comment: A browser will only render styles it understands. There is no way to change this.

Comment: I understand that but what I am looking for is a way that the style attribute in the end will be 
style="column-count:3;-moz-column-count:3;-webkit-column-count:3;" instead of just style="-moz-column-count:3;"

Comment: Perhaps you should explain *why* you need the attribute to contain that whole lot even though it doesn't support it?

Comment: BTW, if you're dealing with browser specific CSS3 styles, check out this great js library which allows you to forget the prefixes (it dynamically converts styles to whatever the browser requires): http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Comment: The why seems not relevant in particular but in general I can make a part of an iPad app text in a basic WYSIWYG Firefox text editor (yes I know it shouldn't be done, but it is), but if I want column-count applied to that text it'll only be -moz-, obviously for it to show up as two columns in the webview in the app it needs -webkit-.  Anyway, I almost have it figured out.  I will try to post the solution when it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The way jQuery works in this respect is that it knows you need a prefixed version. So all you have to apply is "column-count": 2, and depending on the browser that's viewing it, jQuery will add the prefixed version.

So unless it is actually broken on any of the devices, you do not need to worry about adding all the prefixed versions to the style in jQ.